# MYSQL dynamic field with content from other fields

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, field

let's say I have 2 columns in a table, a and b (both plain text).
Is there any way to create a third column c in the same table, with the content of those other columns a and b?

Example:

a/0 = "Peter", b/0 = "Griffin" => c/0 = "Peter Griffin" (space if a != empty)

a/1 = "", b/1 = "The Giant Chicken" => c/1 = "The Giant Chicken" (no delimiter)

This dynamic column c would obviously have to be a read-only field, because there is no way to determine if a space is a delimiter or a regular character.

I use a simple PHP function for getting the contents of a field, so I could have this function check if field c is requested and, if so, return a, maybe a space and b...
But I feel like this isn't the best place to do this check - is there a way to have SQL run this combine procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate them with a simple select

```
select trim(concat_ws(' ',a,b)) from table
```

You can adapt my select to an update statement if you need it.